# Autoconfigure ReactiveCrudRepos in integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test

I'm having some difficulty in writing some Integration tests. I have something like so

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Service.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer();

    @Autowired
    Service Service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host(postgres.getHost())
                .port(postgres.getFirstMappedPort())  // optional, defaults to 5432
                .username(postgres.getUsername())
                .password(postgres.getPassword())
                .database(postgres.getDatabaseName())  // optional
                .build());

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sql.sql");

        Mono<PostgresqlConnection> mono = connectionFactory.create();
        mono.map(connection -> connection
                .createStatement(Helpers.asString(resource))
                .execute()).block();

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Request Request = new Request();
        request.setName("name");
        Mono<Item> itemMono = Service.createNewHub(hubRequest);
        Item item = itemMono.block();

        Assert.assertEquals(1L, 1L);

    }
}
```

And my Service.class looks like the below

```
@Service
public class Service {

    private Repository repository;

    public Service(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Flux<Item> getAllItems() {
            return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And my repo

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Item, Integer>  {

}
```

My error is the following

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.Repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

While all of the code I have written in the application is able to be injected fine, when it comes to the ReactiveCrudRepos, I am not having any luck on getting their instantiated object. What do I need to do to have the implementations created and injected?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use `@SpringBootTest(classes = Service.class)`, the other beans are not loaded into the application context. The annotation element `class` of the annotation is described as:

> The *component classes* to use for loading an [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html?is-external=true).

Remove the element and use the `@SpringBootApplication` as is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Service.class)
public class ServiceTest { /* code */ }
```

Remember, using this way is testing an application context completely different from what will be run on the production environment. It should be a last resort.

---

Moreover, avoid naming the interface `Repository` when there exists the Spring annotation `@Repository` itself. I would personally prefer:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Item, Integer>  {

}
```